# Howto read json from localhost adress in Elm 0.19?

Tags: json, elm, decoder

Do you know a good sample of howto read an JSON API from an localhost adress like: localhost:5050

And read the output of the json api it with elm/json and an simple JSON Decoder?

localhost:8000?

Comment: What do you mean it "crashes"? Elm programs don't normally crash, but return errors. If so, what is the error?

Comment: module Movie seems to be the problem

Comment: I will rewrite it thanos for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elm guide is good place for starters:
https://guide.elm-lang.org/

For JSON Decoders examples specifically, have a look here:
https://guide.elm-lang.org/effects/json.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint!